# Remove "Appendix" title from Cover Page

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I'm writing a report in latex and I included an appendix in my document. When I typeset, the title "Appendix" appears on a page by itself. I want this "Appendix" title to be on the same page as my appendix content. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{Lec2}
\printbibliography

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{stuff} \label{App: AppendixA}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.62]{stuff}
\end{figure}

\chapter{stuff} \label{App: AppendixB}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{stuff}
\end{figure}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove the option `page` when loading `appendix` the page with "Appendices" is not shown. Do you really want a page starting with "Appendices" title and then "Appendix A" in the same page?

Comment: You could just use \addtocounter{page}{-1} and remove the page manually.

Comment: @karlkoeller Wanna convert your comment into a short answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B My comment doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @karlkoeller It was the best bet, i went for it. Close as unclear?

Comment: @Johannes_B No, the question is clear. Just a strange requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to simply remove the `page` option when loading `appendix` so that the page with "Appendices" is not shown.

But if you really want to have the "Appendices" title to be on the same page as your appendix contents, here is a way (I don't recommend to do it, of course).

Add the following lines just after `\begin{appendices}`

```
\clearpage
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\begin{center}
  \Huge\bfseries\appendixpagename
\end{center}
\chapter{stuff} \label{App: AppendixA}
\endgroup
```

and remove the `page` option when loading `appendix`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{appendices}
\clearpage
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\begin{center}
  \Huge\bfseries\appendixpagename
\end{center}
\chapter{stuff} \label{App: AppendixA}
\endgroup

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.62]{stuff}
\end{figure}

\chapter{stuff} \label{App: AppendixB}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{stuff}
\end{figure}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose there is an easy way to place the Appendices title at the same level and then move the Appendix A title down? Also, related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374552/appendices-title-on-first-page-of-appendices-and-not-separate-page