# Appendices title on first page of Appendices and not separate page

Tags: appendices

I have used the appendix package like this.

```
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
```

This puts the title 'appendix' on its own page.  Now I want to have this title, but I would rather if it put on the same page as the first chapter of the appendix, so you would have it just above chapter title of the first appendix.

I tried to read the manual, but I did not see an option for this.

Comment: There is a `title` option but that's not what you want, most likely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with patching of `\@makechapterhead`:

The patch checks whether the chapter number is `1`, i.e. meaning the first appendix chapter and insertes the `Appendix` line accordingly, taking the values of `\abovefirstappchapskip` etc. into account -- those values can be changed at will.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\abovefirstappchapskip}
\newlength{\belowfirstappchapskip}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
  }{%
    \ifnum1=\c@chapter
    \vskip\abovefirstappchapskip%
    \fi
  }{}{}
  \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  }{%
    \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum1=\c@chapter
    \begingroup 
    \centering \Huge\bfseries \appendixname
    \vskip\belowfirstappchapskip
    \endgroup
    \fi
  }{}{}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\abovefirstappchapskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\belowfirstappchapskip}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Foo}

\chapter{Foobar}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution posted worked well.  The solution given after the edit would be preferable but it causes `\chapter{Foobar}` not to display.  I am using lualatex if that possibly makes a difference.

Comment: @MichaelBuckley: Yes, I forgot `\fi` in the first `\xpatchcmd` for `\@makechapterhead`. Please use the updated code, it should work with `lualatex` as well now

Comment: This does not seem to do anything if you have \include{appendix} where the appendix is in another .tex. I placed the patch before my \begin{document}. Compiles without a warning or error. But I still have Appendix A and then the chapter with no Appendix title at the very top.

Comment: @DirkHaupt: Works for me out of the box even with `\include` although I never claimed it would work with `\include` (which I basically never use for my purposes). There's nothing I can do for you here